# SQL Server: flatten an array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id        my_array
-------------------------
1         ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I would like to flatten it so it looks like this:

```
id             my_array
------------------------
1               "a"
1               "b"
1               "c"
```

I have tried with `openjson()` without success.

Comment: try using string_split function in SQl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
      1  id, 
      value my_array 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(replace(replace('["a", "b", "c"]','[',''),']',''),',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(id INT,Field VARCHAR(200))


INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1 ,'["a", "b", "c"]'
UNION
SELECT 2 ,'["x", "y", "z"]'


SELECT A.id,LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(B.value,'"',''),'[',''),']','')) AS my_array
FROM @T A 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(Field,',')) B
```